# Как в заппросе сделать сортировку по 3м полям ?

Tags: сортировка, запрос, mysql

Как в заппросе сделать сортировку по 3м полям ?

```
SELECT * FROM `stats` GROUP BY `logos` ASC,`statos` ASC,`pozos` ASC;
```

Сейчас делает сортировку по 1му полю, по 2м другим что то не хочет, делает вид, что то похоже но не то. Все 3 поля типа `INT`

Answer (score 6):

Так может все-таки стоит попробовать сортировать, а не группировать?

Comment: пока не получается, как

Comment: я еще раз говорю - вы не сортируете, вы группируете. Вы понимаете смысл слов GROUP BY?

Comment: смутно, поэтому попросил помощи
с сортом по несколько полям вообще не получается, а еще естьмысль сделать джойном, но блин то же не умею.

Comment: хорошо, смотрите. Если вы хотите сортировать, то вам надо заменить GROUP BY на ORDER BY. Примерно так: 

    SELECT * 
    FROM `stats` 
    ORDER BY `logos` ASC,`statos` ASC,`pozos` ASC


GROUP BY выполняет, как я уже говорил, группировку. Подробнее почитайте об этом [тут][1] На умные слова вроде "агрегатная функция" можете пока особого внимания не обращать

[1]: http://www.itrecords.ru/osnovy-sql-operator-select-konstrukciya-group-by/

Comment: >а еще естьмысль сделать джойном, но блин то же не умею

JOIN отношения к сортировке как такового не имеет. Он для других целей. Об этом полистайте хотя бы даже в [Википедии][1]

[1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: странно, почему то не сработало

Comment: Видимо потому что вам не сортировка нужна а групировка)